# Add database entries after bundle installation

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-bundle

I'm just looking for a way to further configure an application after the installation of a bundle.

Imagine you have an entity called `Permission`. I want to add a new permission entry to the database after installing the bundle.

Do you have any suggestions?

I already tried composer scripts, but composer will only execute scripts in the root `compose.json`, so that is no option...

Also keep in mind that I look for a way to execute a command, function, or whatever that could contain logic, so a SQL file to migration is not the solution. ;)

Comment: Create a custom Symfony console command that encapsulates the logic for adding a new permission entry to the database, which can be executed manually after installing the bundle.

Comment: i want to run it automatically - an command doesnt help me there :S

Answer (score -1):

You should take a look at flex and flex formulas.
Here is a link: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex_private_recipes.html

As far as I know, it's the only way to do something "automatically" on bundle install. Still, the user will be prompted to ensure the package is trusted before executing it's recipe.